# I cant use persistance in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, permissions, live-usb

I was trying to download a big file but I did not have enough room for it. So, I decided to download it to my `casper-rw` (persistance) drive.

I tried to download it, but it said I did not have permissions to write data on the drive. Well then stupid me thought, let me change the owner of the drive to me so it will work.

But then the next day I wake up realizing that was really dumb because my system wont boot anymore. I get some errors, and then it pops me into a command line login prompt. And I login as user `ubuntu`, and I try to remount the drive and fix it but, it says

`sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owner by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set`

What do I do here? Please help

Comment: It is probably easiest to 1. Boot live-only (without persistence); 2. backup (save) all the files, that are important (personal documents, pictures etc) to another drive; 3. remove all files in the partition (or file) for persistence. -- After that it should work to boot with persistence again. If still problems, use gparted to create a fresh ext4 file system. Then you can reinstall your favourite program packages and restore the files that you backed up. In the future, write to sub-directories in your home directory, which will write into the partition for persistence in an indirect way.

Comment: To mount a casper-rw file so it can be edited: `sudo mkdir /media/casper`  then `sudo mount -o loop casper-rw /media/casper/` and then proceed as sudodus suggests.

Comment: i dont have sudo

Comment: If you boot live-only (without persistence, that is without the boot option `persistent`), you should have `sudo`.